# Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.cli.Main in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I am completely new to intellij, i am trying to run an users.feature in intelliJ getting an error "Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.cli.Main " not sure how to fix it .

Please refer the below screen shot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd99Y.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fsEr.png)

Comment: Is it possible to share your sample project?

Comment: Seems the `cucumber.cli.Main` related library is included in your project, please try to add them to this project.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue by adding proper  dependency in pom.xml
You will get the dependency
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java